# Problem creating a file in a directory if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, io

I have a method that should write information to a file that is in a directory. But I get an error that such file does not exist. I want that if there is no such file and there is no directory either, then they were created
Code:

```
File file = new File("testDirectory/" + "myFile" + ".txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
pw.println("Text");
pw.close();
```

Comment: Here is the _JavaDoc_, for _[File#mkdirs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())_.

Answer (score 2):

check if the directory exists before you write to the file. if it doesnt, create one.

```
if (!directory.exists()) {
  directory.mkdirs(); // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```java
File file = new File("testDirectory/" + "myFile" + ".txt");

file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
pw.println("Text");
pw.close();
```

Comment: 1) still gives error if the directory does not exist( from question: "*there is no directory*"); 2) `createNewFile()` is not needed, [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File)) of `PrintWrite()`: "*If the file exists then ...; otherwise, a new file will be created*"; 3) resources like `PrintWriter` are better handled with `try-with-resources`

Comment: @user85421 mechanical mistake: I forgot to put `file.getParentFile().mkdirs();` before `createNewFile()` after adding directory API for testing second (without directory) case..  thanks. You're right about `PrintWriter(file)` API.